# Shifting indices in functions series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

I'm confused about shifting the index of function series in some situations, in particular where the expression with $n$ that is set equal to a new parameter $t$ is not a function that goes in all $\mathbb{N}$. I'll make an example.

Consider a function $f(n)$ of $n$. If I have a series like
$$\sum_{n\geq0} f(n) \,\,x^{n+1}\tag{A}$$
I have no problem since I can set $n+1=t$ and then write
$$\sum_{t\geq1} f(t-1) \,\,\, x^t$$
And that's should be the same exact thing as $(A)$. Here the "function" at the exponent of $x$,  $g(n)=n+1$ goes from $\mathbb{N}$ **in all $\mathbb{N}$.**

But in some cases like this one:
$$\sum_{n\geq0}f(n) \,\,\, x^{2n+1}\tag{B}$$
If I set $2n+1=t$ and then write
$$\sum_{t\geq1} f(\frac{t-1}{2})  \,\,\,x^t$$
I don't think that this is the same series of $(B)$ because the parameter $t$ takes all natural numbers (even and odd), while $2n+1$ just takes **odd** natural numbers. In other words, the "function" in the exponent of $x$, $g(n)=2n+1$ goes from $\mathbb{N}$ **in the odd natural numbers** and that's a problem because the parameter $t$ is in all $\mathbb{N}$.

---

In general can one shift the index of a series setting $t=g(n)$ with $g(n)$ a function that does not go in all $\mathbb{N}$ but just in some subset of it?

It looks like it should not be allowed because the new series obtained "has more terms" (in the example also even numbers are considered for $t$ but not for $2n+1$).

So, if the shifting I made is incorrect, is there a way to indeed transform series like $(B)$ in power series, that is to have the exponent of $x$ (which is the "function" $g(n)$ I mentioned) as the parameter over which the sum is made?

Comment: The series $\{2n + 1\}_{n \ge 0}$ has the values $1,3,5,7,\ldots$ The series $\{ t \}_{t \ge 1}$ has the values $1,2,3,4,\ldots$. Clearly, these two series are not the same. Instead, if you take the series $\{ t \}_{t \ge 1 \, : \, t \text{ is odd}}$, then you have the values $1,3,5,7,\ldots$ which coincides with the first series we considered. In conclusion, you can rewrite the series (B) to

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t \ge 1 \, : \, t \text{ is odd}} f(\frac{t - 1}{2}) x^t.
\end{equation}

Comment: @Ritz Thanks for the answer! I thought about this, but then can I use all the theorems of power series for 

$$\begin{equation} \sum_{t \ge 1 \, : \, t \text{ is odd}} f(\frac{t - 1}{2}) x^t. \end{equation}$$
even if the sum does not run on all natural numbers but only on odd numbers?

By "theorems on power series" I mean the calculation of the radius of convergence and Abel theorem for example.

Comment: You could always define 

\begin{equation}
g(n) := \begin{cases} f(\frac{n - 1}{2}) & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\
0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then, you can study $\sum_{t \ge 1} g(t) x^t$.

Comment: Ok thanks! If I may ask, is there something similar I can do if I have expressions in the exponent of $x$ that are stranger than $2n+1$ (odd numbers), like $x^{2n-\sqrt{2}}$? In such cases setting $t=2n-\sqrt{2}$ means that $t$ is not a natural number which is a problem if I want a series that runs on $t$, so my guess would be that in that case there is no way to do such shifting, but maybe there is one? (In general I refer to the cases where the function in the exponent of $x$ is a function of $n$ but it's not a natural number, as in the example)

Comment: If you have something like $\sum_{n \ge 0} f(n) x^{2n - \sqrt{2}}$, then you cannot rewrite this into a power series that involves $x^t$, where $t$ is an integer, since this does not exist in the original series. So, no, I do not know if there is a shifting in the cases you describe.